# Cocoa nonatomic properties

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, properties, atomic

When you look at some Objective-C code, you often see class properties defined as non-atomic. Why? Does it give you some performance boost when you're not working with threads, or is there some other reason?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C properties: atomic vs nonatomic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588866/objective-c-properties-atomic-vs-nonatomic)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`nonatomic` accessors are faster because they don't have to lock.  That's about all there is to it.  From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Articles/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1):

> If you do not specify **`nonatomic`**, then in a reference counted environment a synthesized get accessor for an object property uses a lock and retains and autoreleases the returned value—the implementation will be similar to the following:
>
> ```
> [_internal lock]; // lock using an object-level lock
> id result = [[value retain] autorelease];
> [_internal unlock];
> return result;
> ```
>
> If you specify **`nonatomic`**, then a synthesized accessor for an object property simply returns the value directly.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick answer. I knew before how nonatomic properties work, I just didn't know the benefit of using them :-)